# Cannot resolve method ask - Akka Streaming with Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm experimenting with `akka`, and (following the documentation), I have the following code:

```
Source<String, NotUsed> words =
                Source.from(Arrays.asList("hello", "hi"));
        Timeout askTimeout = Timeout.apply(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        words
                .mapAsync(5, elem -> ask(ref, elem, askTimeout))
                .map(elem -> (String) elem)
                // continue processing of the replies from the actor
                .map(elem -> elem.toLowerCase())
                .runWith(Sink.ignore(), materializer);
```

But I cannot find the "import static" directive to make the "ask method" work.
I got:

> Cannot resolve method ask

What i'm doing wrong? I'm using akka v 2.4 (with Java, no Scala) and  following and following step by step the documentation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/stream/stream-integrations.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ask` refers to the ask *Pattern*.

You can use it from java using `import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: **import akka.pattern.ask**